# OSX: ld: warning: bad symbol action: for core libraries

Tags: c++, macos, qt, build, shared-libraries

Building my Qt app on mac, I get a number of warnings:

```
ld: warning: bad symbol action: $ld$install_name$os10.5$/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices in dylib /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
ld: warning: bad symbol action: $ld$install_name$os10.5$/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices in dylib /System/Library/Frameworks//CoreText.framework/CoreText
ld: warning: bad symbol action: $ld$install_name$os10.5$/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices in dylib /System/Library/Frameworks//ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
ld: warning: bad symbol action: $ld$install_name$os10.5$/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices in dylib /System/Library/Frameworks//CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
```

I have placed the Qt frameworks into the bundle and used install_name_tool to create all the dependencies for all my dylibs and executable, as well as within Qt frameworks and plugins. My app seems to work on a non-qt machine.

Still these warnings worry me, I do not want to have my app not work on a different mac... Are they saying hat I have to deploy all the frameworks (CoreServices, ApplicationServices.....) bundled inside my app ? I worry hat will make it too big, and I thought hat these frameworks are pat of any OS ?

I tried to add

```
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
```

but it did not affect these warnings.

What do these warnings mean and what can I do to eliminate them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the network admin has uninstalled then installed an old version of xcode... for an older OS X version... No comment.